# CKEDITOR with custom toolbar and custom styles

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I'm having troubles configuring CKEDITOR to have a custom toolbar with custom styles.

This is the config for the custom styles that i added to config.js

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('custom_styles', [
  { name: 'Text Bolder', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'validate' }}
]);
```

This is the code i use configure the toolbar and the styles and initialize the toolbar

```
var cfg = { 
  toolbar: [
    [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic',{ name: 'Styles'}]
  ],
  stylesSet:  'custom_styles'
};
/* Inline */
CKEDITOR.inline('derecha',cfg);
```

The problem it's with the styles and i don't know why they show empty

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the `<p>` element. The previous code works if the element it's a `<span>` . I think it's because the inline editor is a `<p>` tag

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('custom_styles', [
 { name: 'Text Bolder', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'validate' }}
]);
var cfg = { 
  toolbar: [
   [ 'Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic',{ name: 'Styles'}]
  ],
  stylesSet:  'custom_styles'
};
/* Inline */
CKEDITOR.inline('derecha',cfg);
```